# Dygraphs timestamp with timezone

Tags: timezone, dygraphs

I know there was a lot of discussion about datetime parsing in dygraphs and problems with Javascript. But still, I have a problem how to correctly pass datetime.

I'm using dygraph to show data (points with 5 seconds interval) and it's crucial to have correct datetime. But if I pass datetime as timestamp (1401580800) or as ISO 8601 (2014-06-01T00:00:00+00:00), I always get datetime modified to my local time.

My question is, how to correctly pass the datetime to dygraph so datetime doesn't change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dygraphs use Javascript Dates, which display according to your local timezone (unfortunately, there's no way to display them using an arbitrary timezone).

One solution is to modify the data - I've encountered a similar problem in my own work, and I made a small helper function to make fake Javascript UTC dates (basically ending up with a Javascript date that's actually the wrong time but shows up looking correct when displayed in local time). This worked for my application, which used moments (http://momentjs.com/) to represent dates everywhere unless required by some other library to use Javascript's Dates.

Another (probably more correct) solution is to modify Dygraph's functions to display the right things, as demonstrated in the answer to this post: [Dygraph showing dates in an arbitrary Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196183/dygraph-showing-dates-in-an-arbitrary-timezone/24196184#24196184)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `Date` object will always use the local time of the computer it's running on.  If you don't want that behavior, you'll need to use something else.  Consider building a pre-formatted string using something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and then just pass the string to dygraphs instead of the date.

Comment: But are you sure dygraphs will understand the string?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Dygraph used for plotting data stored without daylight saving. 363 days per year were no problem: JavaScript "believes" it's local time and Dygraph displays the graph as if it was local time. When time changes in spring and autumn in my local time zone, however, this produces a shift in the time axis. I also use now a fake UTC time. This is done by first appending a "Z" to the ISO date and time string passed to the Date constructor of JavaScript. Then the Dygraph object is instantiated with the option labelsUTC: true. In the end, it's not truly UTC, but it's coherent between my database and the graphs displayed.
Now if you need to have the true time zone on the graph itself, my suggestion would be to handle it separately as a single string variable. You can certainly extract it from your data, and then you can display it as a label somewhere near your time axis. This way, you don't have to worry about modifying Dygraph itself.